# How to implement Laravel Email verification for multi auth?

Tags: laravel, email-verification

I follow what the documentation says and it works perfectly fine for single auth (in my case Patient Model). Now, i want to implement it on another user (Doctor). However, based on the documentation, laravel states that the routes responsible for email verification should be named exactly the same. So if i try to create a separate email verification, there would be conflicts on the name of the routes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgzyL.png)

Comment: Please enter the code as text (with code design) and not as an image

Answer (score 0):

If youre using the `bmatovu\multi-auth` package, they have a seamless way that enables you to have multi auth and also leverage on email verification.

You can check out the wiki at https://github.com/mtvbrianking/multi-auth/wiki/Email-Verification

Cheers.

Comment: Im not using any multi auth package. I implement multi auth by adding custom guards and providers in config/auth.php